# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#294)

Tags: oauth, facebook-ads-api

I've been struggling to find out what is happening with this. My scripts were working fine for a bit and suddenly half stopped.

I'm accessing the api and am getting back an access token. With the access token, I can access a users public info just fine. However, when I try to post info to their FB account I get this error.

`Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#294) Managing advertisements requires the extended permission ads_management, and a participating API key thrown in O:\wamp\www\facebook-ads-api\inc\base_facebook.php on line 1106 )`

Comment: please put your code too

Answer (score 1):

I've bumped with this issue, like the message says, the users have to grant `ads_management` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) to your app in order for your app to execute ads actions on the users accounts.

You also need to be whitelisted for access to the Ads API, and must apply for this access on [Facebook's developer site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/)